# Как сделать поинты/валюту на сайте

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Я не знаю как правильно сформулировать вопрос, но попробую.

Мне нужно реализовать свой счет на сайте, тоесть, свои поинты и т.п.
1. Нужно чтобы при покупке продукта, вычиталась его цена из счета пользователя,
если при вычитании счет будет равен <0 то выводилась ошибка
2. Нужно чтобы можно было легко пополнить счет [Например, нажатием на кнопку(+100)]

Мне не нужно чтобы они пополнялись через платёжные системы!

Я пробывал добавлять столбец `quarks`[валюта] в таблицу с профилем и с помощь оператора `UPDATE += '".$user['price']."'` не работало, затем попробывал создать другую таблицу со столбцами `id` `user_id` `username` `quarks` `product_id` и привязывать к профилю, не помогало(вообще ничего не выводило)
скиньте у кого есть, скрипты рабочие

Comment: `UPDATE += '".$user['price']."'` - Такое точно работать не будет ;). Ничего готового нет, просто нужно правильно реализовать, ваша логика более менее правильная. Но нужно только правильно реализовать

Comment: Я знаю, я имел в виду при помощи оператора UPDATE, там у меня UPDATE `users` SET quarks += '".$user['price']."' WHERE user_id = 'user_id'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE `таблица` SET quarks = quarks +'".$user['price']."' WHERE user_id = 'id 
пользователя'
```